# gitlab-runner - run job against multiples runners

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am currently improving our CI to run a job against multiples runners with different configurations (like different OS, ...).

In short, I want to say run all this jobs (a lots), against all the targets (a lots).

Currently I have a working solution but I must copy and paste with a tag each job. This is boilerplate... I am pretty sure there is a solution, but cannot get a held on it.

**One example**

Some information about my sample:

1. We have chained test (non-destructive), who can be run on the same job
2. We have destructive test, where we change the configuration so dramatically, that we cannot chain another tests. So we re-deploy our system before the next job

```
###########
# System tests.
###########
.system-tests-setup:
  stage: system-test
  image: docker.net:5000/our-builder:0.3
  script:
    - set-the-env-for-our-application

.system-tests-non-destructive:
  extends: .system-tests-setup
  script:
    - system_tests/non-destructive-tests.py --stack-ip ${LOCAL_IP} --stack-port 9090

.system-tests-destructive-check-1:
  extends: .system-tests-setup
  script:
    - system_tests/destructive_tests/check-1.py --address ${LOCAL_IP}

.system-tests-destructive-check-2:
  extends: .system-tests-setup
  script:
    - system_tests/destructive_tests/check-1.py --address ${LOCAL_IP}

.system_tests_sbc_poc_requirement:
  extends: .system-tests-setup
  script:
    - system_tests/destructive_tests/sbc_poc_requirements.py --address ${LOCAL_IP}

## Run on ubuntu 18.04.03 - docker 19.03.5
test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5-non-destructive:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-non-destructive
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5

test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5-check-1:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-destructive-check-1
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5

test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5-check-2:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-destructive-check-2
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5

## Run on ubuntu 18.04.03 - docker 18.09.9
test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9-non-destructive:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-non-destructive
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9

test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9-check-1:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-destructive-check-1
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9

test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9-check-2:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-destructive-check-2
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-18.09.9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many jobs that are very similar that can be run on the same runner and/or docker image, then you can use the [parallel](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel) keyword and then external scripts to handle the small changes needed for the different jobs.

You could then use the variable `CI_NODE_INDEX` as an argument to your test script:

```
.system-tests-non-destructive:
  extends: .system-tests-setup
  script:
    - system_tests/non-destructive-tests.py --ci_node_index $CI_NODE_INDEX

...

test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5-non-destructive:
  extends:
    - .system-tests-non-destructive
  tags:
    - test:ubuntu-18.04.03-docker-19.03.5
  parallel: 10
```

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file would then decide on which platform you run your tests, while your external python scripts would contain all the information about how the tests are performed. This could reduce the amount of code you need to duplicate, although it is not a perfect solution.

Another solution could be to just generate the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. Then it should be very easy to add, remove, and change parts of it in any way that you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the script can be a good solution, as we already have a lots of automated scripts inside our project. I will wait a little for a fully .gitlab-ci solution. Otherwise I will accept your solution.